# Required this tree structure json data from response data in angular

Tags: angular

0:{ instrumtfamily:'unalysis' , instrumentline:'cobas 1000',totalactiveinstrumentfamily : 10,totalactiveinstrumentline :5}
1:{ instrumtfamily:'unalysis' , instrumentline:'cobas 2000',totalactiveinstrumentfamily : 10,totalactiveinstrumentline :5}
2:{ instrumtfamily:'Histology' , instrumentline:'cobas 3000',totalactiveinstrumentfamily : 12,totalactiveinstrumentline :3}
3:{ instrumtfamily:'Histology' , instrumentline:'cobas 4000',totalactiveinstrumentfamily : 12,totalactiveinstrumentline :3}

(i am getting this jason data from response)

Resultinstrument=
[
{

```
                             instrumtfamily : unalysis
                             totalactiveinstrumentfamily : 10
                             totalactiveinstrumentline :5
                             unalysis :{
                             instrumentline :cobas 1000
                             instrumentline: cobas 2000
                             }
                       }

                       {
                            instrumtfamily : Histology
                            totalactiveinstrumentfamily : 12
                            totalactiveinstrumentline : 3
                            Histology :{
                            instrumentline :cobas 3000
                            instrumentline: cobas 4000
                                 }

                       }
                  ]
```

(Required this type tree structure from first one response data )

Comment: any one please help me

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i have try so many method but not working @ Mureinik

Comment: can you please help me